# angular10: How to detect complex input object in array change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, detection

I have an array that I use `DoCheck` and IterableDiffer to listen to changes in my code. When the array is changed, but when a property inside one of the objects in the array changes I don't get notified. I tried using `KeyValueDiffer` for each object in the array `types` but it doesn't work in `ngDoCheck`. Any ideas?

In the parent:

```
<comp [types]="types"></comp>
```

```
readonly: boolean =  false;

types: {
  readonly: boolean;
  title: string;
  value: any;
}[] = [{
  title: 'title1',
  readonly: this.readonly,
  value: 1
}, {
  title: 'title2',
  readonly: this.readonly,
  value: 2
}];

ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.readonly = true;
    }, 5000)
}
```

In component `comp`:

```
constructor(
    private differsService: KeyValueDiffers
) {};

@Input() types: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.differ = this.searchTypes.reduce((t, c, i) => {
      t[`types_${i}`] = this.differsService.find(c).create();
      return t;
    }, {});
}

ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this.differ) {
      Object.keys(this.differ).map((key: string) => {
        const k = key.split('_');
        const state = k.length === 1?this[k[0]]:this[k[0]][k[1]];
        const changes = this.differ[key].diff(state);
        if (changes) {
          console.log(key, changes);
        }
      })
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point to be made is that this kind of change detection can be unnecessarily expensive and complicated. I'd recommend reading up on RxJS and how it works to handle changes in data.

In your specific example, however, the problem is not with your key differs, but with the logic of how you're handling `readonly`

In javascript, primitives (such as booleans) are not passed by reference, but by value.

This means that when you set the following:

`readonly: this.readonly`

the value in the `type` for readonly is set to false, and that's it. If later you change `this.readonly` the value within `type` is not changed. If you want to keep the connection between the two "live", you need to pass by reference, with an object, for example. something like

`this.readonly = { status: false }`

Then when you do

`this.readonly.status = true`

that value will be changed in the `types` as well.

Here's a stackblitz demonstrating it in action (and no need for keydiffers):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d8gige?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for reminding this , I ignored the fact that the `type` hasn't changed when I change `this.readonly`,  thanks~.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, change detection is triggered on assignment. This means that you need to assign new value to bound variables or objects to trigger the change detection. So, instead of changing properties on objects only. Try to reassign the array again afterwards to trigger detection:

```
types = [...types];
```

Try assigning that in the parent component when updating the values in types array

```
<comp [types]="types"></comp>
```

This article might help you in understanding that concept:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-change-detection-strategy